# MySQL (OSX) LEFT JOIN not working as expected

Tags: mysql, macos, left-join

Hi: struggling with retrieving only those emails from my marketingImport table that do not exist in my hardBounce table.

I tried various approaches to the LEFT JOIN, but I'm always getting the entire marketingTable (all 300K records). I should be only getting about 220K records, since there are about 80K 'bad' emails in my hardBounce table: those should be excluded from my results.

I also tried replacing WHERE with AND (to make it part of the ON clause), but got same results.

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT marketingImport.email FROM marketingImport
LEFT JOIN hardBounce ON marketingImport.email = hardBounce.email
WHERE hardBounce.email IS NULL;
```

Tables:

-marketingImport contains a field 'email' which is a varchar(255), nullable index

-hardBounce contains a single field 'email' which is a varchar(255), nullable UNIQUE index (not PK)

What am I missing? I did read all posts...and my eyes are now watering...

Thank you.

Comment: It seems all suggested methods return ALL records from the right table, ignoring the NOT IN/NOT EXISTS/IS NULL condition. The performance is better best using NOT IN, then LEFT JOIN, then NOT EXISTS --- but I'm still not getting my results :(.

Comment: Mystery resolved. It appears my hardBounce table's email field had '0D' appended across all 80K records. Hence the consistent perceived malfunction. This appendage likely occurred during export/CSV/Import procedures. I UPDATEd all rows using a REPLACE clause. Then, All suggestions below worked, thank you for help. I'm sticking with the LEFT JOIN, which now works as advertised (on MySQL). Whew...

Comment: That is VERY good to hear, I assumed it must've been a data issue since the 2 queries below didn't work!  ;)  Glad you've got it sorted... the LEFT JOIN is probably a good choice for this.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a subquery instead of `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT marketingImport.email
FROM   marketingImport
WHERE  marketingImport.email NOT IN (
    SELECT hardBounce.email
    FROM   hardBounce
);
```

Comment: Hi: that does not appear to be valid MySQL syntax ... I get a syntax error in SQL workbench... I also worry that subquery would yield inefficinecy, but am willing to try :)

Comment: Sorry, left the "IS" in there! Should just be "NOT IN".

Comment: drats: same result: all 274580 records are being returned in 0.0020 sec

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT marketingImport.email FROM marketingImport
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM hardBounce WHERE hardBounce.email = marketingImport.email
);
```

And I think there may be `null` value in `hardBounce`, so you can get all the the emails from `marketingImport`.